# Making a shareit clone ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making an app that involves sending and receiving files from one iPhone to several other iPhones. I did a lot of googling and came nowhere in finding the classes that support the above said features. I am wondering whether it is possible and if it is possible what are the classes that i can use to do that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my library https://github.com/abdullahselek/Merhaba

you can send data with Bonjour networking